Встроенная функция Python - int()
Почему при вводе встроенной функции int('FACE', 16) с такими параметрами нам выдает ответ:

64206


Спасибо!

Это шестнадатиричное число 0xface / https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

int.

'FACE' - это строка из 4 букв, F, A, C, E.
Из-за того, что вы в качестве второго параметра вызова функции int() указали число 16, Python сначала проверяет, все ли символы в первом параметре являются шестнадцатеричными: либо «обычными» цифрами (0-9), или буквами из диапазона A-F (прописными или строчными — они представляют собой остальные шестнадцатеричные цифры 10-15).
В вашем случае все в порядке, буквы вашей строки представляют собой соответственно цифры 15, 10, 12 и 14, а Python вам выдает ответ в десятичной системе:
                  15 * 163   +   10 * 162   +   12 * 161   +   14 * 160   =   64206.

Ещё есть · и × для умножения.

@Stanislav Volodarskiy, спасибо вам за полезный совет.

В дополнение небольшой код, который делает вычисления, указанные в другом ответе (цифр в 16-ричном числе тут не предполагается, только буквы):
print(sum(16**i * (ord(ch) - ord('A') + 10) for i, ch in enumerate(reversed('FACE'))))
# 64206


16**i - это как-раз 160, 161, 162...
ord(ch) - ord('A') + 10 - перевод 16-ричных букв ABCDEF в числа 10, 11, 12...
reversed - потому что вычислять проще от младших разрядов к старшим, там сразу понятно, что степень начинается с 0, её не нужно вычислять

